# Google meet video freezes for people not talking

Tags: firefox, google-meet

I am using Google Meet on Mac M1, on the Firefox browser. This issue does not occur on Chrome.

When in the grid layout view, all the people who are not talking have frozen video. The person talking usually has correct video, but it also takes time to start moving after they talk.

My internet connection is confirmed to be strong.